# Solr autocomplete keyword and geolocation based

Tags: solr, autocomplete, geolocation

I am looking for getting auto complete suggestions using Solr based on keyword as well as geolocation. Is there a way the 'Suggester' component or any other way, Solr can take in multiple fields for auto completion?

For e.g. if I have a restaurants database and I want to get suggestions using keyword e.g. 'Piz', the results should be based both on the keyword 'Piz' and also the locations that are close to certain latitude, longitude.

Is there a way to do it in Solr ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you create a handler that:

- in the index analyzer chaing, use EdgeNGram to math what the user entered so far
- boost results with geodist(): play around with recip() etc until you get desired weight on the location boosting

call that handler and pass current location and user entered chars and you are done